# JSF: Adding a String to List

Tags: list, jsf

I have an  JSF 2.0 application that has a bean that holds a list of Strings.

I want to add the String from an `<h:inputText>/>` to my List and display my list.

The following code just put references in my List. So every element from my List is set to the last input.

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class Bean {

private String name;
private ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();

public Bean() {
}

public Bean(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String addtoList(String _name){
    test.add(_name);
    return "./index.xhtml";
} 


/***************GETTER/SETTER/HASHCODE/EQUALS**************************/
   ...

}
```

here a part of my index.xhtml:

```
        <h:inputText id="name"
                         value="#{bean.name}"
                         required="true">
        </h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton value="Post"  
                         action="#{bean.addtoList(name)}"/>  
        <br/>
        <h:dataTable var="bean"
                     value="#{bean.test}">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.name}"/>
            </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>
```

[image: apllicationExample]

Comment: `public void addtoList(String _name){
    test.add(_name);
    return "./index.xhtml";
}` This shouldn't compile... what's your exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public String addtoList() { // no parameter
    test.add(this.name); // add value of bean's property
    return "./index.xhtml";
}
```

and in the facelet:

```
<h:commandButton
    value="Post"
    action="#{bean.addtoList}"/> <!-- no parameter passed -->
```

The point is to have the `addToList` method without parameters and the string you add to the list should be the value of the `name` property of the backing bean.

And also, in the datatable, do not name the `var` the same as the backing bean. It's confusing and potentially leads to bugs. Use something like this:

```
<h:dataTable
    var="it"
    value="#{bean.test}">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{it}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: "The point is not to add the name method parameter to the list, but the bean's name property." how should i do that?

Comment: @JavaNullPointer I edited the answer a bit. Is it still unclear to you?

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:dataTable var="beany"
                         value="#{bean.test}">
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{beany}"/>
                </h:column>

</h:dataTable>
```

the prob was that `var="bean"` is the same name of my class `bean`
better should be another name for `var`