# Edit and display list of Strings in view

Tags: jsf

I am trying to learn JSF and doing some basic stuff.

In the `<h:form>` should be an `<h:inputText>` field. The text written in the textbox should be added in an `ArrayList` and this list must be seen in a `<h:dataTable>` under the textfield. I don't know how I can iterate in JSF in an `ArrayList` and print into view. I also don't know how to add `String`s in the `ArrayList`. I have done this with Servlet + JSP but I dont know how to do it in JSF.

..here is my code: http://pastebin.com/3jX1jYXH

Comment: Please edit your code providing the proper JSF code and show what have you tried.

Comment: Dont need help anymore just found the answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609511/jsf-adding-a-string-to-list

Comment: That's a possible solution, but not one to follow if you're in learning phase (as stated in your question). Still, is up to you...

Comment: What do you mean? Bad code?...I am unterstanding the code but I just dont get why he returns this string: return "./index.xhtml";

Comment: First, using `@ApplicationScoped` when it could be `@ViewScoped` or `@SessionScoped` (I would prefer the former). Second, using `ArrayList` attribute instead of `List` backed up by `ArrayList` (refer to [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)). Third, no need to return `"./index.xhtml"` or a `String` at all, the method used for the `action` of the `<h:commandButton>` can *return* a `void` instead to stay in the same view. Fourth, no need to pass a parameter to the action method.

Comment: Last but not least, you can use `<h:dataTable>` or `<ui:repeat>` to show the items contained in your `List`.

Comment: IMO it would be better if you understand the MVC pattern very well: use view logic **only** in the view (in this case, in Facelets), have the controller classes for what they should do: control the flow of the application, and let the model classes (services, data access, entities) handle the model logic (business rules, relationships with database or other data sources, etc). Then, grab concepts from Servlets and understand that JSF is on top of it.